# Flask - Cannot find Blueprint templates on Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I have a Python module with a blueprint like so...

```
import os
from flask import Blueprint


LIBRARY_BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
TEMPLATE_BASE_DIR = os.path.join(LIBRARY_BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_BASE_DIR = os.path.join(LIBRARY_BASE_DIR, 'static')


BulmaBase = Blueprint(
    'bulma',
    __name__,
    url_prefix='/bulma',
    static_url_path='/bulma-static',
    static_folder=STATIC_BASE_DIR,
    template_folder=TEMPLATE_BASE_DIR,
)
```

Registered to a Flask application in a different module `routes.py`

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(BulmaBase)
```

The blueprint has a base template I want to extend in multiple applications.

```
{% extends 'bases/bulma/bulma.html' %}
```

A `main.py` file runs the app via WSGI. The Google App Engine `app.yaml` file has no entrypoint listed (so it should use the default, main:app).

```
application.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=DEBUG)
```

All works perfectly when running locally. However, upon running on Google App Engine, templates in the Blueprint cannot be found. If I disable the Blueprint, the app runs on GAE again.

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: bases/bulma/bulma.html
at _get_source_fast (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py:86)
at get_source (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py:58)
at load (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py:113)
at _load_template (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py:804)
at get_template (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py:830)
at root (/srv/auth_app/templates/BASE.html:11)
at root (/srv/auth_app/templates/login__firebase_ui.html:14)
at render (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py:1005)
at top-level template code (/srv/auth_app/templates/login__firebase_ui.html:1)
at reraise (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py:37)
at handle_exception (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py:780)
at render (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py:1008)
at render (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py:76)
at _render (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py:117)
at render_template (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py:135)
at login (/srv/auth_app/routes.py:64)
at dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1799)
at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1813)
at reraise (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py:35)
at handle_user_exception (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1718)
at full_dispatch_request (/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py:1815)
at wsgi_app (
```

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this issue. In the end, I'd just like to have a shared extendable template (with bundled assets) that multiple other people can extend in their own applications. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `TEMPLATE_BASE_DIR`?  It might be helpful to describe your directory structure.

Comment: just to check, are you adding Blueprint in your requeriments.txt? seems like the app engine isn't downloading the repo. To check to try to download the repo and deploy the app with those templates in the main folder so the app can find the templates

Comment: @gaefan - `TEMPLATE_BASE_DIR` is an absolute path to a templates folder within this module (placed in the same dir as this file)

Comment: @Chris32 Yes, this module is added in the requirements file (from a private Bitbucket repo). I can spin up a new environment locally, run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and have all run perfectly. Deploying the same to GAE fails with the error above.

Comment: Then the problem is how you are calling the private repo. Can you share that part with us?

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer an issue after upgrading the Google App Engine service from the Standard Environment to a Flexible Environment.

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/serving-static-files) -

`Apps in the flexible environment can serve static files from a Google Cloud Platform option like Cloud Storage, serve them directly, or use a third-party content delivery network (CDN).`

Where this fails is that the Standard Environment does not allow for the ability to access/write non-runtime files from external libraries; only a `tmp` folder can be used unless a specific static folder is specified in `app.yaml`. This presents itself, if the app attempts to use any templates from an external library, as an error with finding the template on the file system.

In short - if you have external libraries and want to use templates/static files from them in production (such as with a Flask `Blueprint`) then the GAE Standard Environment will not work as far as I can tell.